# GraphQL how to do a JOIN request instead of many sequential request?

Tags: javascript, typescript, graphql, apollo, apollo-server

I have two GraphQL type:

```
type Author {
  id: String!
  name: String!
}

type Book {
  id: String!
  author: Author!
  name: String!
}
```

In my database, it is implemented by a foreign key inside the books table:

table authors (pseudo code)

```
`id` INTEGER UNSIGNED
`name` STRING
```

table books (pseudo code)

```
`id` INTEGER UNSIGNED
`author_id` INTEGER UNSIGNED REFERENCE `authors.id`
`name` STRING
```

So when I resolve a GraphQL query like:

```
query allTheBooks {
  id
  name
  author {
    id
    name
  }
}
```

I would like to do only one `SELECT` SQL query like:

```
SELECT books.id, books.name, authors.id, authors.name
FROM books
LEFT JOIN authors ON authors.id = books.author_id
```

Instead of the current:

```
SELECT books.id, books.name, books.author_id
FROM books

SELECT authors.id, authors.name
FROM authors
WHERE author.id = [one the the books.author_id of the first SELECT]

SELECT authors.id, authors.name
FROM authors
WHERE author.id = [one the the books.author_id of the first SELECT]

[...]
```

Is there a way to know which "child fields" are queried in a GraphQL resolver ?

**Thank you in advance for your answer !**

Comment: I would add a books field inside the author so you could resolve all the books of the author as well. Like a 2 side way.

Comment: Yep, but it's not related to the question so I kept it as simple as possible.

Answer (score 2):

I just discovered that in the fourth parameter gived at the resolver, there where an array of the queried fields: `info.fieldNodes[0].selectionSet.selections`.

I didn't found any documentation about this, and I wonder what represent the `fieldNodes` array... (and dont like to access the first element that way without knowing it...).

The `selections` object contains an array like this:

```
[
  {
    kind: 'Field',
    alias: undefined,
    name: { kind: 'Name', value: 'id', loc: [Object] },
    arguments: [],
    directives: [],
    selectionSet: undefined,
    loc: { start: 36, end: 38 }
  },
  {
    [...]
  },
  ...
]
```

Here, the `value: 'id'` match the name of the queried field of the related author.

If I go a level deeped, the `selectionSet: undefined` becomes an object and the pattern repeat itself recursively...